# When using .text it returns undefined values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of users that I know has 11 values because when I print to console it displays all the array elements. However, when I use--

```
users.map(printLog)

function printLog(item,index){console.log(item.text);}`
```

It returns 11 undefined values, any suggestions?

I am writing this in react and the actual code snippet I am using is `return <div>{users.map(user=> (<div key={user.id}>{user.text};</div>))}</div>;`

Update: This is the Array returned when printing users. (Sorry I didn't include this initially)

```
{id: "5b27fd770fdd1f04b257dfc2", name: "Kylo Ren", complete: false, __typename: "User", Symbol(id): "User:5b27fd770fdd1f04b257dfc2"}
{id: "5b27fd7a0fdd1f04b257dfc3", name: "Kylo Ren", complete: false, __typename: "User", Symbol(id): "User:5b27fd7a0fdd1f04b257dfc3"}
{id: "5b28070eb9c7600551e5a1c0", name: "Kylo Ren", complete: false, __typename: "User", Symbol(id): "User:5b28070eb9c7600551e5a1c0"}
{id: "5b28076eb9c7600551e5a1c1", name: "Kylo Ren", complete: false, __typename: "User", Symbol(id): "User:5b28076eb9c7600551e5a1c1"}
{id: "5b2807f1b9c7600551e5a1c2", name: "Kylo Ren", complete: false, __typename: "User", Symbol(id): "User:5b2807f1b9c7600551e5a1c2"}
{id: "5b28082eb9c7600551e5a1c3", name: "Kylo Ren", complete: false, __typename: "User", Symbol(id): "User:5b28082eb9c7600551e5a1c3"}
{id: "5b28085cb8b563056546e737", name: "Kylo Ren", complete: false, __typename: "User", Symbol(id): "User:5b28085cb8b563056546e737"}
{id: "5b28085fb8b563056546e738", name: "Kylo Ren", complete: false, __typename: "User", Symbol(id): "User:5b28085fb8b563056546e738"}
{id: "5b28086ab8b563056546e739", name: "Kylo Ren", complete: false, __typename: "User", Symbol(id): "User:5b28086ab8b563056546e739"}
 {id: "5b280872b8b563056546e73a", name: "Kylo Ren", complete: false, __typename: "User", Symbol(id): "User:5b280872b8b563056546e73a"}
{id: "5b280da6a766dd058f73b3bf", name: "Ben", complete: false, __typename: "User", Symbol(id): "User:5b280da6a766dd058f73b3bf"}
```

Comment: share your `user` array.

Comment: We can't help you without knowing what your `users` array looks like. Your code at the end of the question is correct if we make reasonable assumptions (other than that you'll have a `;` in the output you probably don't want, remove the `;` after `{user.text}`). So clearly something isn't as one would assume.

Comment: You can help people help you by doing a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user objects don't have `text` members. Try replacing `user.text` with `user.name` (which is probably what you want, but it's not entirely clear).

Comment: I feel like an idiot, i'm watching a tutorial and forgot I changed my array fields instead of using the tutorials... AHH!!!